# How to fill a hole in plastic window frame?

Tags: windows, hole, plastic

The window balance broke and caused this:

[image: Windows Photo]

Any idea how to repair it? The window frame is plastic. Thanks.

Comment: Is water entry/exit an issue, or do you just need to patch it for looks?

Comment: Water is not an issue at this point, but I suspect it could be (if I leave the window open and it rains).

Comment: You could cut a small block of wood and seal it in with bathtub white silicone. From the photo, the caulking between the window frame and the structure also looks poor. You could cut it away with a utility knife then apply a nice clean bead of white silicone.

Comment: What if I just fill the whole gap with silicone?

Comment: It would be too tricky to get a smooth top surface. Cut a dice of styrofoam just below level with the frame piece. Stick it in place with some caulking. Next day fill all the small gaps to get a smooth look. Dip your finger into dish liquid and water mix to make a smooth bead, then paper towel to clean your finger. I use various caulkings every day: something so simple can look so good.